# Altering Mysql Table column to be case sensitive

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my Mysql database, which is used for authentication. And now, I need to make the authentication case sensitive. 
Googling around, I have realized Mysql columns are case insensitive (contrary to Oracle) for search operations and the default behavior can be changed while creating the table by specifying the "binary" ie.

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    USER_ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(50) BINARY NOT NULL
)
```

Can someone please tell me how to alter the table in Mysql to add the "Binary" to an existing column of a DB?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to make it Binary to make it case sensitive.  If it is a varchar, just use collation = latin1_general_cs

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```sql
ALTER TABLE USERS CHANGE USER_NAME USER_NAME VARCHAR(50) BINARY NOT NULL;
```

For string data types, the BINARY attribute is a nonstandard MySQL extension that is shorthand for specifying the binary collation of the character set.
As of MySQL 8.0.27, this usage is deprecated [[1](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=13068)][[2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-deprecations)]. A character set with *_bin* collation should be used instead, e.g.

```sql
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY user_name VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

Comment: To quote the mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html, "If you want to change a column's type but not the name, CHANGE syntax still requires an old and new column name, even if they are the same."

Comment: In case anyone missed the docs, you can use `MODIFY` instead of `CHANGE` if you're not changing the column name. In that case you only need to provide the column name once.

Comment: @deinst, isn't VARCHAR(50) BINARY the same as VARBINARY(50) ?

Comment: @Levsha not it's not; `VARCHAR(50) BINARY` results in `varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` (actual charset may vary).

Answer (score 10):

Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table MODIFY some_column BLOB;
ALTER TABLE some_table MODIFY some_column VARCHAR(50) BINARY;
```

The first line converts to a binary data type (attempt to minimize character loss) and the second converts back to the `VARCHAR` type with `BINARY` collation.

It may actually be preferable to store as one of the binary types (`BLOB`, `BINARY`, or `VARBINARY`) rather than simply collating `BINARY`. I would suggest you compare a bit, your mileage may vary depending on your actual data and the queries you need to run.

Comment: BINARY attribute is deprecated in MySQL 8.0. See my edit of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3396315/1045774

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do something like this:

Edit: Misread what you intended to do:

```sql
    ALTER TABLE USERS MODIFY
        USER_NAME VARCHAR(50)
          CHARACTER SET binary;
```

Comment: The following worked for me:    ALTER TABLE UserAccounts CHANGE
    Password Password varchar(50) NOT NULL
      COLLATE utf8_bin;

Answer (score 0):

You can go to tables ,find your table ...right click on it .. then choose design option ... Once the design window opens .. under 'Table designer' ( the bottom pane) ..

Find collation  .. it will be set to 'database default' .. change it to Sql_latin_general_cp1_Cs_As( you'll find this option in the drop-down )

Here cs in the above option stands for case sensitive ..

Now click save ..

Your column will be case sensitive now

Answer (score -1):

Rather than altering your table, you can still perform case sensitive queries on your table when authenticating, use the BINARY option as follows:

```
SELECT BINARY * FROM USERS where USER_ID = 2 AND USER_NAME = 'someone' LIMIT 1;
```

Does this help?

Comment: Based on the above, a user name of SomeOne will return false.

Comment: This adds a significant overhead to every single query. If the data must always be returned binary why convert it on every single access? That is what we call "kludge".

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding, will the following statement mean a case SENSITIVE check in the future?

ALTER TABLE USERS CHANGE USER_NAME USER_NAME VARCHAR(50) BINARY NOT NULL;

As far as I understood each and every login authentication needed to be case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response, yes I managed to do it using the ALTER syntax provided by you guys. I was getting confused looking at the charset in the syntax, of the MySQL manual.