# how to make my primary key in MySQL database Works for lower and higher case?

Tags: java, mysql, database, primary-key

I wanna make database which has table contains username and password.

and I want to make username primary key , to prevent duplication.

when I tried to make that , For Example :

1-Admin
2-admin
3-AdMiN
4-ADMIN
5-ADMin
etc ..

all these usernames aren't considered as duplicated.

how can I make these cases are considered as duplication ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying "1-Admin","2-admin" etc... are duplicates?

Comment: i mean admin , Admin , ADMIN , etc ..

i want to make these things considered as duplication ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case sensitive coallation like `utf8_general_cs` on the table. Also your user name should not be the primary key. The PK should jsut be an `auto_increment` integer. If you want to make the username unique just make it a `UNIQUE KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite as you want: [Altering Mysql Table column to be case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396253/altering-mysql-table-column-to-be-case-sensitive)

The person which have post the question says the column is case insensitive by default in MySql.

Another post [here](http://venutip.com/content/case-sensitivity-mysql-do-you-really-need-it) say the same.

Answer (score 0):

The table column in mySql is case sensitive by default and not the other way.