# In Scala, when making a slick sortBy, how can I have it do a case-sensitive sort

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, play-slick

I found the Scala slick package's "sortBy" method is not case sensitive. Ex:
after implementing the following command: `q.sortBy(columnMap("name").desc)`, I got:

TestingIsFun,
testing foo1,
Testing foo,

Is this expected behavior? How can I make it case sensitive? Thx.

Comment: MySQL is not case sensitive. This is usually worked around by adding `BINARY` to the query. *e.g.:* `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY BINARY fullName`. Using an ORM will certainly make that tricky.

Comment: Looks like *["BINARY" in mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)* makes that tricky (as well as ORM)! I did some search but couldn't find the counterpart in Slick. Looks like Slick itself is not able to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as it currently stands, slick just depends on the RDBMS default handling of case in sorting. You did not mention the RDBMS type, but e.g. in mysql, case-insensitive is the default in sorting. However, you can define a column to-be-sorted in a way overiding that, in mysql, as per [Altering Mysql Table column to be case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396253/altering-mysql-table-column-to-be-case-sensitive). This will work without having to touch the query or slick parameters, as the solution is at the schema definition level. It should be possible to define the column as a binary string in the first place, with slick if needed:

`O.DBType("binary")` in the slick column definition should work for that.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the database, the sorting of particular column will be done according to the collation for that column. [By default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html), MySQL uses case-insensitive collation (unless you specify `binary` charset). You can override the default collation on any of the 4 levels (server, database, table or column) or even only in specific ORDER BY clause. Which way is the most efficient, depends on your particular use case. Using case-sensitive collation obviously affects performance, so most of the time it makes sense doing it either on [table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-table.html) or on [column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-column.html) level.